# How to stylize left part of input range in Metro Apps?

Tags: css, windows-8

I am currently trying to stylize an input type range in one of my Metro App. But, I can't find  how to change the default blue/purple color at the left of my control. Any idea?

I succeeded in changing marker and the right part colors with following CSS:

```
html input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  background: yellow;
}

html input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  background: red;
}
```

So, I suppose there must be something similar. But what? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use these CSS classes to style the color of the left side of the range control:

```
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: rgb(0, 130, 135); /* same in dark and light */
}
input[type=range]:hover::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: rgb(33, 146, 151); /* same in dark and light */
}
input[type=range]:active::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: rgb(37, 187, 196); /* same in dark and light */
}
input[type=range]:disabled::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.24);
}
.win-ui-light input[type=range]:disabled::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

Please note that above are the default values, you have to override them with your color.

If you are looking for other color settings of the control or different controls, search for the type of control in the dark-ui.css file. There is a separate section with colors for each control

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!

I tried with the DOM Inspector, but I wasn't able to find these properties. I will have a deeper look on these *-ui.css files. :)